# Jquery checkbox prop method with change event

Tags: jquery, events, checkbox, prop

I need do some actions with checkboxes which was checked from another checkbox. But it's doesn't work. Why? Simple example:

```js
$('.tmp').click(function(){
  $('.quest:not(:checked)').prop('checked', true);  
});

$('.quest').change(function(){
  console.log(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="" id="" class="tmp"> Click me to see some magic... or not(
<br>

<input type="checkbox" name="" id="" class="quest">1
<input type="checkbox" name="" id="" class="quest">2
<input type="checkbox" name="" id="" class="quest">3
<input type="checkbox" name="" id="" class="quest">4
<input type="checkbox" name="" id="" class="quest">5
<input type="checkbox" name="" id="" class="quest">6
<input type="checkbox" name="" id="" class="quest">7
<input type="checkbox" name="" id="" class="quest">8
<input type="checkbox" name="" id="" class="quest">9
<input type="checkbox" name="" id="" class="quest">10
```

Comment: this will not triggered because you need to bind that event in a document.ready function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to manually trigger the `change` event using `trigger` method, for example:

```
$('.quest:not(:checked)')
.prop('checked', true) // updating prop but the change event is not fired
.trigger('change'); // this line will trigger the change event on .quest
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check whether `.tmp` is checked or not, based on that add checkbox property.

```
$('.tmp').click(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $('.quest').prop('checked', true);
    } else {
        $('.quest').prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.tmp').click(function () {
        $('.quest:not(:checked)').prop('checked', true);
    });
   $('.quest').change(function(){
   console.log(this);
   });
});
```